# Show that for every triangle $ABC$ $\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}-\frac{1}{h_a}=\frac{1}{r_a}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area

Show that for every triangle $ABC$ $$\dfrac{1}{h_b}+\dfrac{1}{h_c}-\dfrac{1}{h_a}=\dfrac{1}{r_a}.$$
Let $S_{ABC}=S$. Then $$S=\dfrac{ah_a}{2}=\dfrac{bh_b}{2}=\dfrac{ch_c}{2}\Rightarrow h_a=\dfrac{2S}{a};h_b=\dfrac{2S}{b};h_c=\dfrac{2S}{c}.$$ On the other hand, $$S=r_a(p-a)\Rightarrow r_a=\dfrac{S}{p-a}.$$ where $r_a$ is the exradii.
So $$\dfrac{1}{h_b}+\dfrac{1}{h_c}-\dfrac{1}{h_a}=\dfrac{b+c-a}{2S}.$$ I can't see that this is equal to $\dfrac{1}{r_a}=\dfrac{p-a}{S}.$ Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p$ is the *semiperimeter* $\frac {a+b+c}2$:

$$\frac1{h_b}+\frac1{h_c}-\frac1{h_a}=\frac {b+c-a}{2\color{red}S} = \frac {a+b+c-2a}{2\color{red}S} = \frac{\frac {a+b+c}2-\frac {2a}2}{\color{red}S} = \frac {p-a}{\color{red}S} = \frac1{r_a}$$

Comment: But we have $\dfrac{b+c-a}{2\color{red}{S}}.$

Comment: So it is equal to $\dfrac {p-a} {\color{red}S}$.

Comment: Why? We only have $\dfrac{a+b}{c}=\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{c}$. What are we using here?

Comment: ?? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this property. So the multipliers in the denominator go to the numerator as divisors?

Comment: Imagine extracting the $\color{red}S$ as $\dfrac 1{\color{red}S}$, and use $\dfrac {a+b}c = \dfrac ac + \dfrac bc$. That is one of the reasons why I excluded $\color{red}S$ in the initial answer - for clarity.

Comment: I didn't get that. What do you mean extracting the $S$ as $\dfrac{1}{S}$. Where should I do that? In the denominator?

Comment: $$\dfrac {b+c-a}{2\color{red}S} = \dfrac 1{\color{red}S} \left(\frac {b+c-a}2\right) = \dfrac 1{\color{red}S} \left(\frac {a+b+c-2a}2\right)=\dfrac 1{\color{red}S} \left(\frac {a+b+c}2-\frac{2a}2\right) = \dfrac 1{\color{red}S} \left(p-a\right) = \dfrac {p-a}{\color{red}S}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!